# Facebook Canvas remove outer scroll

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, canvas

I am trying to remove the Outer scroll of the Facebook canvas while keeping the inner Iframe scroll I have.

I have tried using FB.Canvas.setSize() and the FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(), I also tried with fluid height and without. while the auto grow does remove the scroll it actually overrides my internal FB app scroll which I need to keep my header static.

I know also there is no way to change the outer frame's css so overflow:hidden will not work for the outer frame and for the inner it negates what Im trying to achieve.

is there any way to remove just the external scroll or make the canvas inherit my Iframe height?

**UPDATE**
well I found something that would work but it aint so pretty.
Im running an interval every X seconds to push the scrollbar to the top
something like:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({
            height: angular.element('body').height()
        });
        $interval(function () {
            FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }, 100);
```

it solves my problem but is by no means an elegant solution...still looking for something better